# Can I set Ubuntu or Fedora to use a UAC-style prompt when something fails due to privileges?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, uac, elevation

Can I set Ubuntu or Fedora to use a UAC-style prompt when something fails due to privileges? As in, in Nautilus, when I open a .run installer and it requires root, can I have it automatically burst an elevation prompt like the one in gksudo or the Software Centre?

Comment: Are you looking for a screen-dimming option as well?  Is this for general use or for a development  environment?